# NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:EsbuildBundle - Esbuild Failed

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

Below is the version of the tool used.

```
➤ sam --version
SAM CLI, version 1.95.0
➤ node -v
v20.5.1
```

I am currently trying to build a Lambda using Layer.

I tried to build using aws-sam-cli, but Esbuild gave me an error importing layers.

```
{'BuildMethod': 'esbuild', 'BuildProperties': {'Minify': True, 'Target': 'es2022', 'Sourcemap': True, 'EntryPoints': ['app/app.ts']}}        
architecture: x86_64 functions: TestFunction                                                                                   
Running NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:CopySource                                                                                                   
Running NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:NpmInstall                                                                                                   
Running NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:EsbuildBundle                                                                                                

Build Failed
Error: NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:EsbuildBundle - Esbuild Failed: ✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "/opt/nodejs/dist/db"

    app/app.ts:6:19:
      6 │ import { Db } from '/opt/nodejs/dist/db';
        ╵                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

1 error
```

The Lambda template.yaml can be found here.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
    test

Parameters:
    Prefix:
        Type: String
        Default: '__PREFIX__'

Globals:
    Function:
        Runtime: nodejs18.x
        Timeout: 10
        MemorySize: 128
    Api:
        OpenApiVersion: 3.0.1

Resources:
    TestFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
            FunctionName: !Sub '${Prefix}-test'
            CodeUri: ../src
            Handler: app.lambdaHandler
            Architectures:
                - x86_64
            Layers:
                - !ImportValue MysqlLayer
            Role: !GetAtt TestFunctionRole.Arn

        Metadata:
            BuildMethod: esbuild
            BuildProperties:
                Minify: true
                Target: 'es2022'
                Sourcemap: true
                EntryPoints:
                    - app/app.ts

    TestFunctionRole:
        ...
```

Information on tsconfig.json can be found here.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2022",
        "strict": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

I heard that setting External may solve the problem, but when I actually set it, the build error was resolved, but the Lambda stopped working with an error.

```
External:   
　　- '/opt/nodejs/dist/*'
```

After reviewing the error, my sense is that the module on the layer side has not been resolved.

```
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'mysql2/promise'\nRequire stack:\n- /opt/nodejs/dist/db/index.js\n- /var/task/app.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'mysql2/promise'",
        "Require stack:",
        "- /opt/nodejs/dist/db/index.js",
        "- /var/task/app.js",
        "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
        "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1061:17)",
        "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1093:21)",
        "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1256:23)",
        "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1262:1"
    ]
}
```

The directory structure is shown here.

```
.
├── README.md
└── business
    ├── nodeLayer
    │   └── db
    │       ├── cf
    │       │   ├── samconfig.toml
    │       │   └── template.yaml
    │       ├── dist
    │       │   └── db
    │       │       ├── index.js
    │       │       ├── index.js.map
    │       │       ├── testDb.js
    │       │       └── testDb.js.map
    │       ├── jest.config.ts
    │       ├── package-lock.json
    │       ├── package.json
    │       ├── src
    │       │   ├── index.ts
    │       │   └── testDb.ts
    │       └── tsconfig.json
    ├── testFunc
    │   ├── cf
    │   │   ├── samconfig.toml
    │   │   └── template.yaml
    │   └── src
    │       ├── README.md
    │       ├── app
    │       │   └── app.ts
    │       ├── jest.config.ts
    │       ├── package-lock.json
    │       ├── package.json
    │       └── tsconfig.json
```

I would like to know how to solve this problem aleva.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your layer dependencies to `External` as well. For example, if you use `some-lib` you need to add it to External

`package.json`

```json
...
"dependencies": {
  "some-lib": "^1.0.0",
}
...
```

`template.yml`

```yaml
...
External:
  - "some-lib"
...
```

Also, make sure that your layer compiled code shows up in `.aws-sam` directory along side your lambdas. Remember you need to include your layer node_modules in your layer compiled code.